# How can I format a variable and make it into a string with a message and zeros in front of it?

Tags: c#

My code has this for PhraseNum:

```
public string PhraseNum { get => _phraseNum; set => SetProperty(ref _phraseNum, value); }
```

What I would like is for instead of just displaying the number, that it displays something like this:

```
Id: 00044
```

So with the characters "Id:" in front, then a space and then padded to five digits.

Comment: Take a look at `string.Format` method. But in your case `string.PadLeft` would be more helpful.

Comment: Try *string interpolation*: `$"Id: {_phraseNum:d5}";` where `d5` stands for **5** digits (format string)

Comment: I did this but it is not giving my five digits with leading zeros.  If the number is for example 79 then I just see Id: 79 when I would like to see 00079.  I think it might be because _phraseNum is already a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way is to call the `ToString` method on the int object with a format:

```
using System.Globalization;

int _phraseNum = 123;
_phraseNum.ToString("Id: 00000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //outputs "Id: 00123"
```

Comment: I recommend using the `String.ToString( IFormatInfo, String )` overload with an explicit `CultureInfo` (`InvariantCulture` or `CurrentCulture`) argument.

Comment: Thanks, I have used ToString before but had no idea I could put all of that formatting in the ()

Comment: Glad i could help! If this answer was helpful please mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public string PhraseNum { get => $"Id: {_phraseNum:D5}"; set => SetProperty(ref _phraseNum, value); }
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the $ at the start does?  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2: `$` stands for *string interpolation* - code within `{...}` will be interpolated (not printed as it is)

Comment: It allows you to inject value inside string in appropriate position  and it looks more intuitive. 

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: I did this but it is not giving my five digits with leading zeros.  If the number is for example 79 then I just see Id: 79 when I would like to see 00079

Comment: @Alan2, of course it gives, did you check it?  `:D5` part is format.